# Partition the list by group of Arithmetic Progression

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I have a list= {4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 7, 9}

How can i partition the list by group of Arithmetic Progression with common difference  1 :

{{4}, {8}, { 10, 11, 12}, {14}, {16}, {7}, {9}}

Comment: Would `Split[list, #2 - #1 == 1 &]` do? However I'm not sure why 7 and 9 are grouped together in your output.

Comment: @Macob  Exactly what I want!
Short and Efficacious!! Thanks.
Yes, I was wrong on the 7 and the.  They are not grouped.

Comment: Great! I've posted it as an answer then!

Answer (score 4):

I think there is some ambiguity here. `{4,8}` could certainly be an arithmetic progression. Also, why not `{14,16}`? Anyway, here's my attempt. It gives something different that your expected output, but I think it satisfies the requirement that each group is an arithmetic progression.

```
MakeArithGroups[list : {_}] := list;
MakeArithGroups[list : {_, _}] := list;
MakeArithGroups[list : {a_, b_, rest__}] := MakeArithGroups[{{a, b}}, {rest}];
MakeArithGroups[prev : {___List}, {}] := prev;
MakeArithGroups[prev : {___List, {a_, b_, ___}}, rest : {x_, ___}] :=
  If[
    x - b == b - a,
    MakeArithGroups[Insert[prev, x, {-1, -1}], Rest@rest],
    MakeArithGroups[Insert[prev, Take[rest, UpTo[2]], -1], Drop[rest, UpTo[2]]]]
```

Demo:

```
MakeArithGroups[{4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 7, 9}]
(* {{4, 8}, {10, 11, 12}, {14, 16}, {7, 9}} *)
```

(This has only been lightly tested.)

Comment: Thanks, But I wanted a group by  arithmetic progression with a common difference of 1.
MarcoB's solution works fine for me with "Split".

Answer (score 4):

```
list= {4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 7, 9};

Split[list, #2 - #1 == 1 &] 

(* Out: 
{{4}, {8}, {10, 11, 12}, {14}, {16}, {7}, {9}}
*)
```